# jquery file-upload submit form on enter key press

Tags: jquery, file-upload

first thanks a lot to people who made such a great tool as file-upload.
I use file-upload (autoUpload:true) on a form with some other different input fields and because of file-upload, when I press "enter" key, nothing happen whereas I would like that this submit all my form.

is this possible ?

thanks

Comment: Anything is possible if you put enough time into it. what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `keyUp` event attached to the body. 13 is the key code for the enter key.

```
$("body").keyup(function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which)
    if(code == 13) {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

If you want other key codes, see [HERE](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: thanks a lot, that is perfect, I just had to change keyUp by keyup as keyUp was not recognize

Comment: @user2016483 No problems! Glad I could help! Ah that was my bad, I edited it :)